# Restricting an alexa device to only one skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to restrict an echo dot to allow only my skill to be invoked on the device. This is a publicly available device so I don't want users making Alexa repeat what they say or set alarms, or basically just using any other skill than the ones I allow. How would I go about restricting access to all other skills?

I've tried going into my Amazon account to see if there were any settings I could manage, but I had no luck. Is it simply not possible to do this right now?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case you may want to look into Alexa for Business: https://aws.amazon.com/alexaforbusiness/

Comment: this is not (yet) available outside US. any alternative?

Comment: the other alternative would be to implement AVS on your own device (not an Echo)

Comment: Were you able to solve this, Henry A. ? I was wondering if perhaps parental control could be a way. Thanks